# How to get a set of numbers with a rule in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, optimization, range

I'm making a function that shows the range of a character in a 2D turned based game (such as advance wars).
My function should find all the coordinates within the movement range of the selected character.
I got the function to do what I want, but my process seems wasteful.
Is there a better way to get the list of coordinates that I'm looking for?

```
func checkMov(for node: SKSpriteNode) {
        let movRange = 3 //for testing purposes
        
        let map = self.childNode(withName: "BattleTileMap") as! SKTileMapNode
        let location = node.position
        let col = map.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: location)
        let row = map.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: location)
        
        for x in row - movRange...row + movRange {
            for y in col - movRange...col + movRange {
                if abs(x-row) + abs(y-col) <= movRange {
                   lightTile(at x: x, y: y)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCZxp.png)

Comment: So you are getting only the coordinates within a certain Manhattan distance to (row, col)?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the coordinates you are trying to get forms a "square" that's rotated 45 degrees around (row, col) like this:

[image]

We just need to loop through all the coordinates in this square, without going through anything that's not in the square (i.e. waste).

For the leftmost x coordinate, we get only `col` as the y coordinate.

For the next x coordinate (one unit to the right), we get the range `col-1...col+1` as the y coordinates.

For the next x coordinate, we get `col-2...col-2` as the range of y coordinates, and so on.

That is until we reach x=`row`, when we get `col-range...col+range` as the range of y coordinates. After that point, the range of y coordinates start to shrink.

Writing this in code:

```
let xRange = (row - range)...(row + range)
for x in xRange {
    // the graph of the below formula is in the shape of a triangle, with the axis
    // of symmetry at x=row. Basically, it's the top half of the rotated square
    let yRadius = range - abs(x - row)
    let yRange = ((col - yRadius)...(col + yRadius))
    for y in yRange {
        lightTile(at x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

This isn't as readable as your original code, and I wouldn't imagine it to be a *lot* faster as you scale up. If I were you, I would choose to keep the readability and not worry about the "waste".